# Matlab: How to set the dimension of the Dwork vector as dynamically in Level 2 Matlab S-Function?

Tags: matlab, simulink

How could we deal with the following statement when we want to obtain a dynamic sized Dwork Vector? The programming environment is not C/C++ S-function but Matlab Level 2 S-function.

```
block.Dwork(1).Dimensions = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Dwork sizes cannot be dynamic. You probably have to declare a large enough size and then store the length of valid elements in your Dwork as a separate Dwork.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I have done. I just wonder why the Mathworks has not developed this dynamic sized Dwork in Matlab Level 2 function. It should be an essiential part in the state vector declaration.